# How to filter array of object by value React Redux lodash

Tags: reactjs, redux, lodash

I have some stupid problem - I can't understand where is my mistake

I have reducer which looks:

```
import startsWith from "lodash";

const arr = [{id: "55ae8f78-4563-4445-b75f-267fe02c00a8", name: "Licensed Car", price: "775.00", discount: "68%"},
{id: "7d30c1c1-dd02-49cd-8b02-d8c3ec301d70", name: "Handmade Mouse", price: "349.00", discount: "71%"},
{id: "5f383f37-d9b1-4494-ac2f-d1ecb72a78f3", name: "Licensed Shirt", price: "425.00", discount: "69%"},
{id: "5ae0de55-f7e6-4d59-bebd-9b215d327efb", name: "Intelligent Chips", price: "767.00", discount: "62%"},
{id: "231a1dc1-1cf8-4b5e-bc3a-9b23932492e8", name: "Refined Cheese", price: "367.00", discount: "80%"}]

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  time: undefined,
  products: arr
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case "FILTER_BY_VALUE": {
      return {
        ...state,
        products: [
          ...state.products.filter(product =>
            startsWith(product.name.toLowerCase(), payload.toLowerCase())
          )
        ]
      };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I also use lodash method "startsWith"

```
_.startsWith([string=''], [target], [position=0])

_.startsWith('abc', 'a');
// => true

_.startsWith('abc', 'b');
// => false

_.startsWith('abc', 'b', 1);
// => true
```

With payload is all okay, I want to filter an array and leave only those elements whose value name is the same or partly the same with the payload.

If someone knows another way to fix my problem without lodash - please write your ideas.

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, vanilla JS has the same `startsWith` method as a lodash lib.

```
case "FILTER_BY_VALUE": {
  return {
    ...state,
    products: [
      ...state.products.filter(product => product.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(payload.toLowerCase()))
    ]
  };
}
```

Comment: @Anon click the tick button to mark the question as answered.